# How to define "anonymous namespace" in C#?

Tags: c#, namespaces

In C++, in order to define a symbol that is only accessible within the same file, we say

```
namespace 
{
    class my_private_class
    { ... }
}
```

But can I do the same thing in C#? Or do I have to say

```
namespace __DO_NOT_USE_OUT_OF_.xxx.cs__ 
{       
  public MyPrivateClass 
  { ... }
}

using __DO_NOT_USE_OUT_OF_.xxx.cs__;
```

(assuming this is in a file called xxx.cs)?
 The later, of cause, will depend on the other programmer regards it or not.

Comment: No, but you could consider scoping `MyPrivateClass` inside of another class, if it's only going to be used by that class.

Comment: Note: Anonymous namespaces should not be confused with unnamed namespaces ([here's a question on that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25491518/4975230)). If you omit the `namespace` specification in the file completely, the classes in the file are said to be part of an unnamed namespace [(see MSDN)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/namespace#remarks), and they will go into the `global` namespace. This is NOT the equivalent of a C++ anonymous namespace.

Answer (score 3):

There's no *anonymous namespaces* in C#, but you can exploit *static classes*:

```
namespace MyNamespace // <- Just a namespace
{
    // Anonymous Namespace emulation:
    //   static class can't have instances and can't be inherited, 
    //   it's abstract and sealed
    internal static class InternalClass // or public static class
    {
        // private class, it's visible within InternalClass only  
        class my_private_class 
        { ... }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing in C#, we have something called [access modifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) which manage the visibility of types.

The usage is against a class or method, such as:

```
internal class MyType 
{

}
```

Or

```
protected void MyMethod() 
{

}
```

You will have to pick the one that applies to your scenario, here are the details:

**public**

The type or member can be accessed by any other code in the same assembly or another assembly that references it.

**private**

The type or member can be accessed only by code in the same class or struct.

**protected**

The type or member can be accessed only by code in the same class or struct, or in a class that is derived from that class.

**internal**

The type or member can be accessed by any code in the same assembly, but not from another assembly.

**protected internal**

The type or member can be accessed by any code in the assembly in which it is declared, or from within a derived class in another assembly. Access from another assembly must take place within a class declaration that derives from the class in which the protected internal element is declared, and it must take place through an instance of the derived class type.