# What namespace will a class have if no namespace is defined

Tags: c#, namespaces

In C#, if I create a class with no namespace, what namespace will I use when trying to instantiate the class?

For example, assume main is...

```
namespace NamespaceTests
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

... and assume my namespace-less class is ...

```
public class test
{
    public string SayHello()
    {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

... and assume I have another class by the same name, but having the default namespace...

```
namespace NamespaceTests
{
    public class test
    {
        public string SayHello()
        {
            return "Hello Moon...";
        }
    }
}
```

... how would I modify main to include an instance of the namespace-less class and call 'SayHello' to retrieve the message "Hello World!"?  Specifically, how would I fully qualify the namespace-less instance of class 'test', especially considering I may have another class also called 'test' but having a namespace, so I need to distinguish...

Comment: possible duplicate of [explicitly refer to a class without a namespace in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767782/explicitly-refer-to-a-class-without-a-namespace-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

It's in the [global namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713620.aspx) and can be referenced like this:

`var x = new global::test();`

Comment: Thanks David - example worked perfect.  Your answer was 10 seconds before @itsme86 -  award to you sir.  +1 for example...

Comment: This solved an ambiguous reference due to a class named the same. One had a namespace and one didn't. It was attempting to call the one with the namespace and getting an exception:  error CS0117: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelperExtensions' does not contain a definition for 'RenderPartialViewToString

Answer (score 17):

Types not defined within a namespace will be in the [global](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713620.aspx) namespace.

> The global contextual keyword, when it comes before the :: operator, refers to the global namespace, which is the default namespace for any C# program and is otherwise unnamed.
>
> The following example shows how to use the global contextual keyword
> to specify that the class TestApp is defined in the global namespace:

```
C# class TestClass : global::TestApp { }
```

Answer (score 5):

In the addition to above answers, it is important to note, what all Type, regardless of its declaration location, has a "fully qualified name", which begins from "global::"

From "O'Relly. C# in a Nutshell":

*All type names are converted to fully qualified names at compile time. Intermediate Language (IL) code contains no unqualified or partially qualified names*

Comment: It's true that you can program in C# using fully qualified objects and avoiding `using` statements.  The `using` statements are purely syntactical sugar which compresses the code to make it easier to read.  When there is a large degree of confusion around classes with similar names it may make sense to fully qualify types and not have `using` statements for extra clarity.