# How to Disambiguate Between External Class and Nested Class

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, nested, disambiguation

I have a situation in which one of my classes is called `SpaceMine`, and another class I have is called `Ability` and has a class nested within it called `SpaceMine`:

```
public class SpaceMine
{

}

public class Ability
{
    public class SpaceMine :  Ability
    {
        void Foo()
        {
            SpaceMine spaceMine;
        }
    }
}
```

Within `Foo()`, I'm trying to declare a variable of type `SpaceMine` (not `Ability.SpaceMine`), but it keeps saying that my variable is of type `Ability.SpaceMine`. Aside from changing the names, how can I ensure that the compiler knows which type I'm trying to declare?

Comment: Firstly, it absolutely kills readability, dont use in real project

Comment: You're better off not nesting them and using a prefix/suffix e.g SpaceMineAbility. Nested classes besides the occasional struct will give you hours of headache a month down the line

Comment: can you be more specific about how it kills readability and can cause headache? to me, it looks much more organized and makes much more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use explicit declaration

```
namespace SpaceName
{
    public class SpaceMine
    {

    }

    public class Ability
    {
        public class SpaceMine :  Ability
        {
            void Foo()
            {
                Ability.SpaceMine nestedMine; //Nested
                //Ability is reducant but it improves readability a little
                SpaceName.SpaceMine globalMine; //Not nested
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see. If I'm not mistaken, isn't there a `global` namespace that all classes not in a namespace default to? I tried that but it the compiler didn't seem to understand what I wanted to do.

Comment: @AgentTatsu yes, there is global namespace (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25491518/what-namespace-will-a-class-have-if-no-namespace-is-defined) but it's not a good practice - you should use namespaces everywhere to not lose your work ;)

Answer (score 0):

I expect you'd simply have to use the full path.

I assume SpaceMine is inside a Namespace - and if it's not, you need to wrap the entire file in a namespace.

Then you can do `new YourNamespace.SpaceMine();` to get the parent one, or `new YourNamespace.Ability.SpaceMine()` to access the nested one.

I wouldn't recommend doing this though as the readability is severely impacted.