# error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PlayerMotor' could not be found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making up my first game in unity and this error is showing up i don't know if i can use a "using" tag would fix this problem or not and i don't know which one

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    [RequireComponent(typeof(PlayerMotor))]
    public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public LayerMask ourMovmentMask;

        Camera cam;
        PlayerMotor motor;
        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start()
        {
            cam = Camera.main;
            motor = GetComponent<PlayerMotor>();
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                Ray ray = cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
                RaycastHit hit;
                if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100, ourMovmentMask))
                {
                    Debug.Log("we hit " + hit.collider.name + " " + hit.point);
                    // move player to what we hit

                    // stop focusing any objects
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to encapsulate your class in a namespace...

Comment: You can put using statements inside of namespaces [See this StackOverflow question asking about the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125319/should-using-directives-be-inside-or-outside-the-namespace). There are lots of times that scripts created inside of Unity will not include a namespace.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 ... I don't know why this is upvoted so much but what are you talking about?? The only case where you **need** to encapsulate something in a namespace is when you either want to hide it or something with the same name already exists in another namespace. The issue here is rather that the type isn't even found...

Comment: @Eliasar the issue seems not to be **where** to put a `using` statement but rather that the type `PlayerMotor` isn't even found due to either simply a missing `using` statement (no matter if inside a namespace or not) or it doesn't exist maybe due to compiler errors etc

Comment: Can you tell us what `PlayerMotor` is? Did you implement this or did it e.g. come from a downloaded asset? If you comment all lines regarding `motor` out are there any other compiler errors in the Unity console?

Comment: @derHugo You know, I always assumed it was a syntax error to not have your classes encapsulated in a namespace for C# since everything is generated by default that way.  TIL

Comment: @derHugo it was a download asset, and when i comment the lines the are no errors

Comment: @derHugo a corollary to my comment about Unity creating scripts is that other scripts and components generated in this fashion [will exist in the global namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25491518/what-namespace-will-a-class-have-if-no-namespace-is-defined). You're right, that the using statements were not the issue. That comment was about the comment above and not the post. I should have used "@" and the commenter.

Comment: You should open the file `PlayerMotor.cs` and see whether there is a `namespace XYZ` statement. If this is the case then you have to put a `using XYZ` on top of your script or alternatively change every line to use `XYZ.PlayerMotor`

Comment: well that was troublesome thank you all for helping

Answer (score 0):

You require the game object to have a "PlayerMotor" Component.

Did you define a PlayerMotor class? If not then define it, as the compiler can not find the class.

If yes then check if it's in your project directory