# Property under private interface always returns zero

Tags: unity-game-engine, interface, properties, private

I have a private interface for a property, so that only its owner class could create or read it, but when I assign to it, it just stays zero.

```cs
var key = new Key();
((IKey)key).Value = 9;
Debug.Log(((IKey)key).Value);
```

Output: 0

```cs
private interface IKey
{
    int Value { get; set; }
}

public struct Key : IKey
{
    int IKey.Value { get; set; }
}
```

Edit: I'm also very curious about the reasons why assignment doesn't work when casting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is more simple solution

```
class Program
{
    private interface IKey
    {
        int Value { get; set; }
    }

    public struct Key : IKey
    {
        int IKey.Value { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        IKey key = new Key();
        key.Value = 7;
        System.Console.WriteLine($"key = {key.Value}");
        System.Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not be casting `key` to `IKey` before setting the value. It already inherits that type and you're masking the `Value` property set up in `Key`. As an aside, this is an instance where I prefer to use strong typing instead of weak typing using `var`. See below:

## Console Program

```
namespace Console
{
    interface IKey
    {
        int Value { get; set; }
    }

    public struct Key : IKey
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var key = new Key();
            ((IKey)key).Value = 9;

            var secondKey = new Key();
            secondKey.Value = 9;

            var thirdKey = new Key();
            thirdKey.Value = 9;

            System.Console.WriteLine($"key = {((IKey)key).Value}");
            System.Console.WriteLine($"secondKey = {((IKey)secondKey).Value}");
            System.Console.WriteLine($"thirdKey = {thirdKey.Value}");

            System.Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

## Output

```
key = 0
secondKey = 9
thirdKey = 9
```

Comment: It doesn't allow me to access Value without casting, says it doesn't exist.

Comment: That does not seem possible, given that the code in this solution is complete. You might have issues if you are using other namespaces

Comment: It definitely doesn't compile. The most simple class with Key interface, Key struct, and one method trying to access it. Unity project, no namespaces.

Comment: You do actually have a namespace with Unity with C#. See [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25491518/what-namespace-will-a-class-have-if-no-namespace-is-defined).

Comment: No idea what you are trying to say.

Comment: If you don't define a namespace in your script, C# will use the default global namespace. My assumption before was that your namespaces were different. There should be no reason that you have to cast your variable back to `IKey` when `Key` already inherits it.

Comment: I wasn't surprised that I have to cast since it's an explicit private interface implementation. I am really surprised that it allows me to assign after a cast (as it should), but then pretends that assignment never happened. Does your code compile for you?

Comment: Yes. This code compiles for me just fine. I think the problem is with the scope and resolved class of your variable when you use `var`. `var key = new Key()` is going to be a `Key`. If you cast that variable to `IKey` and set that `Value`, the private scope of `IKey.Value` is not accessible through `get` of `Key.Value` and 0 is returned (default value of `int`)