# 'Employee' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017, c#-3.0

When I am trying to built the code in visual studio,it's showing error as

1. 'Employee' is a type, which is not valid in the given context.
2. Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
   Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'C1' could not be found (are you 
   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
   SecondC C:\Users\ypoint\source\repos\SecondC\SecondC\Program.cs 36

I am new to the C#, Please help me out from this issues.

```
using System;

public struct Emplyoee
{
    private int _Id;
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    public int ID
    {
        get { return this._Id; }
        set { this._Id = value; }
    }

    public Emplyoee(int Id, string Name)
    {
        this._Id = Id;
        this._name = Name;
    }

    public void PrintDetails()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Id={0} && Name={1}", this._Id, this._name);
    }
}

public class Program
{ 
    public static void Main()
    {
        Emplyoee C1 = new Emplyoee(101, "Sudharshan");
        C1.PrintDetails();

    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried with vs 2017 c# 3.0 and it works for me and outputs **Id=101 && Name=Sudharshan**, i think your problem source is different

Comment: Add your project's namespace block to have this code and try.

Answer (score 2):

Your classes should be defined within a namespace, such as:

```
using System;

namespace Organization.Solution.Project // quite a regular way to define a namespace 
{
    public struct Emplyoee
    {
        // ...
    }

    public class Program
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now the Program class knows the struct Emplyee because they reside in the same namespace. Not doing so means your classes are in the [global namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25491518/what-namespace-will-a-class-have-if-no-namespace-is-defined).

In order to keep code files shorter, you may prefer to have 2 files:

- Program.cs with the Program class, enclosed in the `namespace Organization.Solution.Project`
- Emplyoee.cs with the Emplyoee struct, enclosed in the `namespace Organization.Solution.Project`