# I'm trying to change var value in one script from another in c# in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two scripts button.cs attached to Start button object and with flag var in it. And Restart.cs attached to RestartButton object. I'm trying to change bool flag from Button.cs in Restart.cs.
And I get this error:

```
Assets\Scripts\Restart.cs(14,63): error CS0122: 'Button.flag' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

This is button.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Button : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public GameObject m_cube, obeme, resetButton;
    public AudioSource audioSource;
    public bool flag = false;
    void  OnMouseDown(){
       
        if (!flag)
        {
        flag = true;
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 180);
        m_cube.GetComponent <Animation> ().Play ("cubeGoDown2");
        audioSource.Play();
        obeme.GetComponent <Animation> ().Play ("obemeGetIn");
        resetButton.GetComponent <Animation> ().Play ("RestartButtonGetIn");
        } 
    }
}
```

And this is Restart.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Restart : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public GameObject resetButton;
    void  OnMouseDown()
    {
    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0,0);
        

       GameObject.Find("Start button").GetComponent<Button>().flag = false;;
    
    resetButton.GetComponent <Animation> ().Play ("RestartButtonGetOut");
    }
}
```

Comment: Button class name is used by Unity UI system so you should change your class name something unique.

Comment: you can use `GetComponent<global::Button>` to specify you want the Button you've made in the global namespace.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What namespace will a class have if no namespace is defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25491518/what-namespace-will-a-class-have-if-no-namespace-is-defined)

Answer (score 0):

The button class Start Button is a preDefined string for unity. so i suggest one of two things.

first: //create a straight reference from your reset to your start button

```
   //like this

   //Variables
   public GameObject myStartButton;

 public GameObject resetButton;
    void  OnMouseDown()
    {
    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0,0);
        

       myStartButton.flag = false;
    
    resetButton.GetComponent <Animation> ().Play ("RestartButtonGetOut");
    }
```

or just easily make the name unique.