# Is there a reason for giving the class holding Main() a namespace in C#?

Tags: c#, namespaces, program-entry-point

After attempting to research C# namespaces further (coming from a c++ background) I think I understand the purpose of namespaces in general - to organise classes for the user, and to avoid conflicts. This practise, I imagine, still holds just as true for programs as it does for libraries.

What I don't understand is why exactly classes housing the Main() function would need to be part of a namespace.

I can't imagine that the main function would need to be called elsewhere for any reason, so organisation and conflict prevention ought not to be the reason.

Is it simply to show other developers what namespace to use throughout the rest of the program's classes? Or is there some deeper reason for it that is going over my head?

Comment: Wrong assumptions lead to wrong conclusions.

Comment: Being in a namespace allows the `Program` class containing the `Main()` method to easily access other types being in the same namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I don't understand is why exactly classes housing the Main() function would need to be part of a namespace.

For sake of simplicity, we're going to assume that the class that contains `Main()` is called `Program`.

The Program class does not *need* to be in a namespace. For example, [explicitly declaring the class](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgPgAQMwAIECY0EYDsKDeAsAFAplqoIAsKAstDABQJYAMA2gLooQBOA5gGcAlARLkJ2AHQsAnIwBEACygLhAbnHkAviV3ESMCGACmggA4QAxiboBPAHLGzlm2NLlkaTABEIAFwh3SQkvWH8UADUIABsCfhN/dUFE9W1yLTJ9bSA===):

```
// Program.cs
public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        System.Console.WriteLine("hi");
    }
}

namespace MyNamespace {
    public class Data {
         public int Val {get;set;}   
    }
}
```

or using [Top Level Statements](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgPgAQIwDpkE4AUAiAFlbASgG4BYAKApgjAFMBnABwgGNaACAWQE8A5GhszbsA3hXYT2CAMxSATOwAiEAC4RR4yVqmzYK9gDUIAG1EBzWiuL1LxAL6TNEuxTtA)

```
// Program.cs
System.Console.WriteLine("hi");

namespace MyNamespace {
    public class Data {
         public int Val {get;set;}   
    }
}
```

SharpLab (the links above) shows you what the compiler will output, and in both the Program class doesn't exist inside a namespace, even though other classes will.

And for the record, this is not limited to the Program class. You can put any/all of your types in the ["global" namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25491518). You just lose the "categorization" benefit of namespaces.

> I can't imagine that the main function would need to be called elsewhere for any reason

I'd agree. *Normally* you'd let the .Net runtime call your Main method. I'm sure you can think of *some* reason to do so, but really that's up to the architecture of your application. One *maybe* valid use case would be automated testing with a testing framework (xUnit, MSTest, etc) in a sibling assembly.

Now, say you *did* want to call the Main method yourself, as long as the Fully Qualified Type doesn't conflict with something else, you can still call it just like normal.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void DoThing() { }
}

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class Data
    {
        public void ActivateDoThing() => Program.DoThing();
        // or, if you run into a conflict
        public void ActivateDoThing() => global::Program.DoThing();
    }
}
```

> Is there a reason for giving the class holding Main() a namespace in C#?

This is due to the editor you're using. Except for the Top Level Statements feature,  when you create a new project with the "Console Application" template, it will have the Program class wrapped in a namespace, which is consistent with creating a new code file for a new class. This is just a decision the authors of the template have chosen, but at least it does follow the rule that every file has a namespace block. Familiarity can enhance readability, even if its inefficient.

That's really the point of the Top Level Statements feature - get rid of all the boilerplate. Technically, you don't need a namespace for the entry point class - so get rid of it. Most of the time, you don't add anything to Program besides the Main method, so don't require the user typing the class or method signatures. Just let the user get to the Main logic as fast as possible and the compiler can generate the rest.

That's really about it. Why is the namespace there? Mostly for consistency. Does it *need* to be there? Nope, not at all.